# Same code works on Linux but not on windows

Tags: c, cs50, long-integer

This is the credit problem from CS50x
I wrote this code on Windows and it didn't work there. After entering a 15 digit card number on windows it wasn't accepting the number and was prompting me again and again.
But when i pasted the same code on CS50's cloudspace in VSCode which is on linux, the code runs perfectly fine there.
The issue seems to be in the get_long function, it wasnt letting me input a 15 digit card number on windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int main()
{
   long number;
   
    number = get_long("Enter your card number: ");
   
   //Check length of number
   int i = 0;
   long length = number;
   while (length > 0 )
   {
    length = length / 10;
    i++;
   }

    if (i != 16 && i != 15 && i!= 13)
    {
        printf ("INVALID");
    }
    else
    {
        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        long x = number;
        int mod1 = 0;
        int mod2 = 0;
        int d1 = 0;
        int d2 = 0;
        int final_sum = 0;

        do
        {
            //Remove last digit and add to sum1
            mod1 = x % 10;
            x = x / 10;
            sum1 = sum1 + mod1;
            
            //Remove second last digit
            mod2 = x % 10;
            x = x / 10;

            //Multiply second last digit by two 
            mod2 = mod2 * 2;

            //Extract the digits
            d1 = mod2 % 10;
            d2 = mod2 / 10;

            //Add to sum2
            sum2 = sum2 + d1 + d2;

        } while (x > 0 );

        final_sum = sum1 + sum2;
        
        //Check Luhns Algorithm
        if (final_sum % 10 != 0)
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
        else
        {
            long y = number;
            int j = 0;
            do
            {
                y = y / 10;
                j++;

            } while (y > 100 );

            if ( y / 10 == 4)
            {
                printf ("VISA");
            }
            else if ((y / 10 == 5) && (0 < y % 10 && y % 10 < 6))
            {
                printf("MASTERCARD");
            }
            else if ((y / 10 == 3) && (y % 10 ==4 || y % 10 == 7) )
            {
                printf("AMEX");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you are calling `get_long_long` you should also use `long long` datatype instead of just `long`

Comment: Perhaps because `long` has only 32 bits. Please change track: use a string for a "number". It is not an integer. Nobody uses an integer to store card, phone, or house "numbers". Anyway, having the digit string makes it rather easy to pick out individual digits, don't you think?

Comment: @WeatherVane `long` is in fact only 32 bits on Windows.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, sorry I though that was what I wrote. Not "perhaps" it is 32 bits, but the reason for failure.

Comment: @WeatherVane I didn't read it that way.  Been a long day for me.  :-/

Comment: @UnholySheep sorry i fixed that to just get_long earlier , then also it didn't work
editing it here as well......

Comment: @WeatherVane *Nobody uses* Well, except legions of CS50 programmers, of course...

Comment: @SteveSummit well, yes. The assumptions that a number is `int` or `long` etc, and that a character is `char` is a frequent pitfall even among non-CS50 learners.

Comment: @WeatherVane currently im a newbie, maybe i'll pick up on these tricks once i get some experience...

Comment: @AndrewHenle okay so maybe thats causing the bottle neck.. but what should i use then because they only taught us till long :I

Comment: You should not wait until then: don't get off on the wrong foot.

Comment: @FaraazHussain The point is that if you're trying to work with a number one digit as a time (as of course you need to do for Luhn validation) it's just plain easier to work with the "number" as a string.  This isn't an advanced "trick" — it's taking the easy way out!

Comment: The only special trick you need to know is that if you've got a string containing digits, the digits are going to be *characters*, with values like 48, 49, and 50.  So you'll need to subtract 48 to get a useful digit value to work with.  But then trick #2 is that you don't have to know that magic number 48, after all, because you can just use the constant `'0'`.  (Apologies if these "tricks" sound cryptic, but they're super handy once you "get" them, and there are thousands of nice, long explanations of them here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on the net.)

Comment: @FaraazHussain I've never really looked at CS50, so I don't know: Does the Luhn exercise come before you've learned about strings?  If so, then this is kind of a bum steer we're giving you.

Comment: @SteveSummit Although most of the things went over my head ryt now......will surely try to implement them.... Thanks

Comment: @SteveSummit Just checked the "cover page" for this (week 1) problem on the CS50 collection... Quote: `Best to use get_long from CS50’s library to get users’ input. (Why?)`... The question is left as an exercise for the reader... ("Hand rolled" solutions are not recommended here, either.) `:)`

Comment: The relevant point about using an implementation with 32-bit `long` is that it can only hold 9 decimal digits. A 64-bit `long` though can hold 19 decimal digits. Neither though, will "remember" if the number has any leading zeros, such as a phone number might have. The C standard only says that `long` must have *at least* 32 bits, and `long long` *at least* 64 bits.

Comment: @SteveSummit: The [instructions for the task](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/credit/) explicitly state the following: `"But do not assume that the user’s input will fit in an int! Best to use get_long from CS50’s library to get users’ input."` This task is part of problem set 1, which is supposed to be completed after week 1. But it is only in week 2 in which students learn the memory representation of a string, for example that it is terminated by a null character. Therefore, OP is supposed to use an integer, not a string.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow is the *de facto* help desk for the free-enrollment version of CS50, we need to figure out what sort of backchannel we can devise from Stack Overflow back to the CS50 instructors.  For we've just clarified a long-suspected bug: advising use of `get_long` for a credit card number might work on modern x86_64 Linux and Mac platforms, but evidently *not* on Windows, or various older platforms.  (But now I understand why so very, very many CS50 students show up here with this exact same problem...)

Answer (score 4):

Your code works because on your Linux platform, type `long` happens to be an 8-byte, 64-bit type that can easily handle integers matching even 15- or 16-digit credit card numbers.

Your code fails on Windows because there, type `long` is a 32-bit type, not capable of handling numbers greater than 2,147,483,647 or 4,294,967,295 (depending on whether signed or unsigned).

This discrepancy between the two platforms is not a bug: C's `short`, `int`, and `long` types have always been somewhat loosely defined.  The requirement for type `long` is, in effect, that it have *at least* 32 bits, which on both platforms it certainly does.

It was rather unfair and misleading for your assignment to have said "Best to use `get_long` from CS50’s library to get users’ input".  This is a nonportable programming practice for this task.

In portable C, type `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits long, so it would work reliably here.  I do not know if CS50's library has a `get_long_long` function.  (Update: per comments below, it does.)

In the long run, it's generally easier to deal with credit card numbers as *strings*, not integers.  But during week 1 of CS50, students haven't learned about strings yet.

Comment: Apparently CS50 does have [`get_long_long`](https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_long_long) but that page says: *This function will be deprecated in favor of `get_long`*.

Comment: @SteveSummit Welcome to CS50.  I'd say it's quite revealing they've deprecated the only way they have for Windows users to read a 64-bit integer value from the user...  :-/

Comment: Using long long sovlved the issue.... Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

The [instructions for your task](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/credit/) state the following:

> But do not assume that the user’s input will fit in an `int`! Best to use `get_long` from CS50’s library to get users’ input.

This advice is misleading when using the Microsoft Windows [platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform).

On Microsoft Windows, the data type `long` has a width of only 32 bits, whereas on most other common platforms, such Linux and MacOS, it has a width of 64 bits. The [ISO C standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) only requires `long` to have a minimum width of 32 bits, so all the mentioned operating systems are complying with the standard in this respect.

A 32-bit `signed` integer is able to represent numbers up to `2,147,483,647`, whereas a 64-bit `signed` integer is able to represent numbers up to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. Therefore, a 32-bit integer data type is insufficient to represent a credit card number; you require a 64-bit integer data type.

In constrast to `long`, the data type `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide on all platforms.

For the reasons stated above, if you want your program to work on Microsoft Windows, you will have to use the `long long` data type to represent a credit card number, instead of `long`. You will also have to use the function [`get_long_long`](https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_long_long) instead of [`get_long`](https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_long).

Comment: Here's the source, for anyone so inclined : https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/main/src/cs50.c

Comment: See the source I linked.  It has a `get_long_long` function.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for that link.  Skimming it quickly, it looks like they really are assuming a platform with 64-bit longs — both `get_int` and `get_long` contain aspects of that assumption.

Comment: yeah, using `long long` solved the issue, thanks....

Answer (score 1):

The discussion in the comments of 32-bit v. 64-bit should be educational for you, and I hope that you can integrate that information into your program.

Compliments to the layout and logic of your *beginner* code. Very clear and very easy to read and follow (including appropriate comments.) Keep this up and you will become a fine programmer!

I've revised your code (without appreciably changing any of its logic) to suggest how it may be slightly improved. The following is offered for your consideration. It is your code only slightly modified. It's up to you to consider if you want to apply any of these "alterations" to your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int main()
{
    long number = get_long("Enter A card number: ");
    long x = number; // will reload and reuse x several times
    int i = 0; // handy to have around

    // Check length of number
    while (x > 0 )
    {
        x = x / 10;
        i++;
    }

    if (i != 16 && i != 15 && i!= 13)
    {
        printf ("INVALID");
        return 1; // early termination saves one level of indentation
    }

    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    int mod1 = 0;
    int mod2 = 0;
    int d1 = 0;
    int d2 = 0;
    int final_sum = 0;

    x = number; // reload
    while ( x > 0 )
    {
        //Remove last digit and add to sum1
        mod1 = x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
        sum1 = sum1 + mod1;

        //Remove second last digit
        mod2 = x % 10;
        x = x / 10;

        //Multiply second last digit by two
        mod2 = mod2 * 2;

        //Extract the digits
        d1 = mod2 % 10;
        d2 = mod2 / 10;

        //Add to sum2
        sum2 = sum2 + d1 + d2;
    }

    final_sum = sum1 + sum2;

    //Check Luhns Algorithm
    if (final_sum % 10 != 0)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
        return 1;  // early termination
    }

    x = number; // reload
    while ( x > 99 ) // NB! subtle change!!
    {
        x = x / 10; // shrink until 10 <= x <= 99
    }

    if ( 40 <= x && x <= 49 ) // check this
    {
        printf ("VISA");
    }
    else if ( 50 <= x && x < 56 ) // check this
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD");
    }
    else if ( x == 34 || x == 37 ) // check this
    {
        printf("AMEX");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
        return 1; // early termination
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: umm thanks for the compliments, but i couldn't really do this problem myself and had to search for the solution to understand the logic :'(
Considering they didn't teach us anything regarding digits extraction, only some loops and if else, thats it. Initially i did solve the problem myself but that was hella inefficient bcz i manually extracted all the digits(couldn't figure out how to convert that to a loop) but that didn't work, maybe that was bcz of that `long` having 32 bit issue....

Comment: Your code is certainly a much more optimised one, now when i look towards mine it has very unnecessary things now (especially when checking the Luhn's algo)
Thanks a lot....

Comment: @FaraazHussain It's okay, when starting out, to use lots of `printf()` statements that inform you of what the variables and their values are doing... Once you get your feet firmly on the ground, shift to a proper debugging utility program to set breakpoints and monitor values to follow how the flow is going and what's happening to the data.  I use an old compiler only capable of 32bit integers... Still good 'nuff to play with writing code for algorithms. Here's a challenge: imagine the CC checker has to run on a tiny device (no 64bit registers) How would you solve it then? Best wishes! `:)`

Comment: @FaraazHussain (Hint to that challenge: Ask the user to enter "XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX", for instance, then grab 4 separate low value integers that each easily fit into 16 bits. `:)`